# What happens to the sequence $a_n=\frac{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Another Evaluating Limit Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139494/another-evaluating-limit-question)

What happens to the sequence $a_n=\frac{3\cdot 5\cdot7\cdot\ldots\cdot (2n-1)}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot\ldots\cdot 2n}$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$? Would appreciate a sort of "proofish" thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens to $b_n=\log(a_{n+1})-\log(a_n)$ when $n\to\infty$?

Comment: The title of the duplicate is definitely better than the other title.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936236/sum-of-the-series-frac12-cdot-4-frac1-cdot32-cdot4-cdot6-dots) is somewhat related

Answer (score 0):

You can write the sum as:
$$S=\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{2k+1}{2k}$$
The result is
$$S=\frac{2(\frac{1}{2})^{N+1}2^{N+1}\Gamma(N+\frac{3}{2})}{\Gamma(N+1)\sqrt{\pi}}$$

The limit of $S$ for $N\to \infty$
is $\infty$

Comment: That doesn't look right. You have $(\frac{1}{2})^{N+1}$ right next to $2^{N+1}$.