# Finding a limit of a sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following sequence I'm having trouble calculating the limit of.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1\times3\times5\times\cdots\times(2n-1)}{2\times4\times6\times\cdots\times(2n)}$$
I got to the point where I found out this is a monotonic decreasing sequence in the range (0,1) I know it converges to 0, I'm just having trouble proving it. Any help would be great!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Another evaluating limit question: $\lim\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139494/another-evaluating-limit-question-lim-frac1-cdot3-cdot5-cdot-ldots-cdot2n-1)

Answer (score 6):

You can multiply numerator and denominator by $2\times 4\times 6\times\cdots\times (2n)$ to get $$\frac{1\times 2\times 3\times\cdots \times (2n-1)\times 2n}{(2\times 4\times 6\cdots \times 2n)^2}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!n!}=\frac{1}{4^n}{2n\choose n}$$

Now you need to estimate ${2n\choose n}$.  You can do this via [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), or directly using bounds on the [Central Binomial Coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient).  Your intuition is correct, the limit is zero.

Comment: this is the idea i have got at first sight.. not the stirlings formula and all but the idea of multiplying numerator and denominator by that number.. but then i had no idea what to do after that.. I would be thankful If you can let me know if there any other way to do from this other than this stirlings formula...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
Prove by induction that
$$x_n=\dfrac{1\cdot{3}\cdot\ldots\cdot{(2n-1)}}{2\cdot{4}\cdot\ldots\cdot{(2n)}}<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If
$$P=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^N(2k-1)}{\prod_{k=1}^N2k}$$
$$P=\frac{\Gamma(N+1/2)}{\sqrt\pi \Gamma(N+1)}$$
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}(P)=0$$