# How to prove that $\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

So guys, how can I evaluate and prove that $$\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=0.$$ Any ideas are welcomed.

$n!!$ is the double factorial, as explained in this  [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) post.

Comment: Do you intend to use the *double factorial*, or simply the factorial of the factorial? I'd assume the double factorial, but I'm just checking...

Comment: An involved way that will work: Rewrite everything to pure factorials and use Sterlings approximation.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=0,\qquad\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\infty,\qquad\quad\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)!!\cdot(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!\cdot(2n)!!}=\frac2\pi$$

Comment: What exactly do you denote $n!!$ ?

Comment: Take the log. You'll get $\sum_i \log\frac{2i-1}{2i}\approx \sum_i -\frac 1 {2i}=-\infty$, hence the original limit is $0$.

Comment: Speculative: $(2n-1) < 2n$ thus $(2n-1)!! < (2n)!!$ thence the denominator goes to infinity faster than the numerator (they have also the same degree). Thus as $n$ approaches to infinity the denominator "wins", and the limit is zero.

Comment: @KimPeekII Yeah, I realise that but it's not really a good proof.

Comment: I know :) I was just speculating a bit, if you want a rigorous proof, this can only gives you the "idea" of what you should obtain in the end. I'm writing down some idea right now, I'll write an answer later!

Comment: Can you use Stirling's formula?

Comment: @DanielFischer Never heard of it, but would be nice for my own knowledge.

Comment: Stirling formula applies for the simple factorial as:

$$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

Comment: I have no idea if such a formula for $n!!$ does exist..

Comment: Stirling's formula says $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n} \bigl(\frac{n}{e}\bigr)^n$. There are further terms, but those suffice here. Then you can rewrite $$\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}$$ (or, depending on the used convention for $(2n)!!$, you get some constant factor times that), and with Stirling's formula you get the asymptotic $\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ (or that times a constant).

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1554790/evaluate-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac2n-12n

Comment: All: A question merger explains why this question "suddenly" got more answers in Dec'15.

Comment: See also: [Another evaluating limit question: $\lim\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/139494)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because missing context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are asking for an idea, then you can use property of [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html). Click the given link, take a look equation $(9)$ and $(11)$. You will obtain
$$
\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^n\ n!)^2}=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2},
$$
then use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)
$$
n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 10):

You can notice that $$\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k}
= \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right).$$

So you want in fact calculate the infinite product
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)$$

Now you can use this fact: [How to prove $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-a_n) = 0$ iff $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n = \infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519656/how-to-prove-prod-i-1-infty-1-a-n-0-iff-sum-i-1-infty-a-n)

In fact, for this you do not need the equivalence, only one implication is sufficient: 
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (1-a_k) \le \frac1{\prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)} \le \frac1{1+\sum_{k=1}^n a_k}.$$
(We assume that $0<a_k<1$.)

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a good and fast way to solve it, but I'm looking for a way to solve it without using sum series since we "didn't learn them yet".

Comment: @user1640736 Knowing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1n)=+\infty$ would suffice for this, but this is just a different way of writing $\sum \frac1k = +\infty$.

Comment: the other way to see this is to take logs which turns it into a normal sum, then use first order taylor expansion, to show the log goes to $-\infty$, so the original series goes to 0.

Answer (score 8):

After some research and thinking I have realised the following :

We can observe that : $$(2K-1)*(2K+1) <  (2K)^2$$

Now, if we give values to K ( from 1 to n ) and the multiply all of them together we get :
$$ 1 * 3^2 * 5^2 * ... * (2n-1)^2 * (2n+1) < 2^2 * 4^2 * ... * (2n)^2 $$

Now by dividing with $2n+1$ and the right side plus taking the square root of the entire identiy we get :

$$ {\frac {(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}} <  {\frac {1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}}$$

Since the second term has the limit 0 as n goes to infinity and the left side is positive we get that :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}} =  0$$

Answer (score 3):

Using 
\begin{align}
(2n-1)!! &= \frac{2^{n} \Gamma(n+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}} \\
(2n)!! &= 2^{n} n!
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(n+1)}.
\end{align}
Now using the duplication formula, $\Gamma(2x) = (2\pi)^{-1/2} 2^{2x-1/2} \Gamma(x) \Gamma(x+1/2)$, this fraction becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{1}{4^{n}} \binom{2n}{n}.
\end{align}
Since $4^{n}$ grows faster than the binomial component it is then seen that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} \right] = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[ \frac{1}{4^{n}} \binom{2n}{n} \right] \rightarrow 0.
\end{align}

Comment: The thing you just state without proof "since $4^n$ grows faster than the binomial component" is basically the same type of question as the one being asked... This is to me a refrashing and not a proof.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $(2n)!$
$(2n)!$=$2n(2n-1)(2n-2).........2(1)$
     =$[(2n-1)(2n-3).....1][(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4).....2]$
     =$(2n-1)!!$$2^n$$n!$
which gives $(2n-1)!!=(2n)!$$/$$2^n$$n!$
$(2n)!!$$=$$(2n)(2n-2)........2$

    =$[2n][2n-2][2n-4]....2$

    =$2^n$$n!$

 

 so $(2n-1)!!$$/$$(2n)!!$$=$$(2n)!!$/$4^n$$[$(n)!$]^2$ 
$(2n-1)!!$$/$$(2n)!!$$=$$2n\choose n$$4^n$
using Stirling's Approximation
$2n\choose n$$=$$(2n/e)^{2n}\sqrt{2\pi*2n}$/$(n/e)^n\sqrt{2\pi*n}$
$=$$4^n$$[(n/e)^{2n}2\sqrt{\pi*n}]$/$[(n/e)^{2n}{2\pi*n}]$ 

$=$$4^n$/$\sqrt{\pi*n}$

which gives

$(2n-1)!!$$/$$(2n)!!$$ = $1/$\sqrt{\pi*n}$

finaly the limit $n$$\longrightarrow$$\infty$

$=$$0$

Answer (score 3):

**May this help a bit?**

For positive integers, those relations hold:

$$(2n)!! = 2^n n!$$

$$(2n-1)!! = \frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$$

But I guess that your case need the general $n$ not only integers..

**EDIT DUE TO THE COMMENTS BELOW**

Using the relationships above and the Stirling approximations below, we find:

$$\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{(2n)!}{(2^n n!)(2^n n!)} = \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}$$

Applying the Stirling approximations:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} (n!)^2} = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi 2n} \left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{2^{2n}(2\pi n)\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Chic goes to zero as $n$ goes to $+\infty$

Comment: We didn't study factorials from anything else but integers, also positive integers. Not sure if those formulas help but they sure are interesting!

Comment: @user1640736 Good! Then if you use them, and you use them with Stirling, namely:

$$(2n)! \approx 2\sqrt{\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}$$

and 

$$(n!)(n!) \approx 2^{2n}(2\pi n)\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}$$

You will get at the end:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

which tends to zero as $n$ goes to infinity!

Answer (score 2):

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=0\quad$ and $\quad\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\infty.~$ Where it really gets interesting, however,

is when we attempt to evaluate their product. Their polar-opposite tendencies will cancel each

other out, yielding $~\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\cdot\dfrac{(2n+1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\dfrac2\pi~,~$ which is the famous [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product).

See also [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) for more information.

Comment: This is awesome for my own knowledge but doesn't really help me solve the limit :)

Comment: @user1640736: This is only meant to supplement the other answer. I can't think of a better way than the one already presented.