# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} {\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}}$

Tags: limits, infinite-product, factorial

I have tried using Stolz–Cesàro's formula and subtract the next term in the series but that gave me $$\lim_{n\to \infty} {\frac{2n}{2n+1}}$$ which is obviously 1 and not right. I do realise that the limit should be 0 but I don't know how to prove it.

***Edit due to comment:***

$n!!$ is the double factorial, as explained in this  [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) post.

Comment: Now I found this older question, which seems to be about the same thing: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788096/how-to-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-frac2n-12n-0