# Infinite product proof without using gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, infinite-product

How do you show that the infinite product of $(3n+1)/(3n+2)$ converges to zero without using the gamma function (as I can tell the gamma function solution has already been presented here)?

I've tried using a number of different strategies, but I still don't seem to be able to land on a good approximation.

Comment: See the answers to this [similar question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphisms_of_the_symmetric_and_alternating_groups), and consider the reciprocal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an elementary argument to show that $\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{3n+1}{3n+2}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046867/is-there-an-elementary-argument-to-show-that-prod-n-0-infty-frac2n12n)

Comment: Actually, the duplicate is about $\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{an+b}{an+c}$, in particular for $a=3$ and $b=1$,$c=2$. There are many answers, not using $\Gamma(s)$.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with infinite product of positive real numbers, it is
always a good ideal to consider the log-transform. Let $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
be defined by $f(x)=x+\ln(1-x)$, then $f'(x)=-\frac{x}{1-x}$. This
shows that $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-1,0]$ and strictly decreasing
on $[0,1)$. In particular, $f(x)\leq f(0)=0$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$.
That is, $\ln(1-x)\leq-x$, for all $x\in(-1,1)$. We need this fact
at later time.

Let $P_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{3k+1}{3k+2}$, then we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln P_{n} & = & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{3k+2}\right)\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=1}^{n}-\frac{1}{3k+2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $0\leq P_{n}\leq\exp\left(-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3k+2}\right)$.
Note that $-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{3k+2}\rightarrow-\infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.
Therefore $P_{n}\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MR1992 Up-vote?