# How to solve the limit $\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k} (k!)^2}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

How to solve this limit??

> $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k} (k!)^2}$$

It's a limit, not a series

Comment: I found that the answer is 0, however, I need to prove it.

Comment: HINT: note that $2^{2k}(k!)^2=\left(\prod_{j=1}^k 2j\right)^2=(2n(2n-2)\cdots 2)^2$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: The SAME limit is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788096/how-to-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-frac2n-12n-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that $\lim_{n \to\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788096/how-to-prove-that-lim-n-to-infty-frac2n-12n-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}\cdot(k!)^2} 
&=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(2k)!}{2^k \cdot 2^k \cdot k! \cdot k!} \\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(2k)!}{(2^k \cdot k!)^2} \\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(2k)(2k-1)\cdots(2)(1)}{(2k)^2 (2k-2)^2 \cdots (4)^2 (2)^2} \\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{(2k-1)(2k-3)\cdots(1)}{(2k)(2k-2)\cdots(2)} \\
&=0
\end{align}

In the last step, you can think of the fraction as the infinite product of fractions less than $1$ ($\frac{1}{2} \times\frac{3}{4} \times \frac{5}{6} \times\frac{7}{8}...$), which will decrease to $0$.

Comment: Not all such products converge to zero. This one may but it isn't automatic just from factors less than $1.$ Actually the product is of terms $1-(1/(2k))$ and so since the sum of the subtracted part goes to infinity you do have product zero here.

Answer (score 0):

This is the probability of having $n$ heads and $n$ tails in $2n$ times of a fair coin toss. This probability then simply goes to 0. You can also use the Stirling's approximation to attain this.